# Disable iOS QuickPath feature for keyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I use a code where I manage a tip and looks like it has some loop when I try to use `QuickPath` typing from the iOS keyboard.

After a loop I have a crash:
[image]

How to disable QuickPath for app? I know it could be just a quick workaround. Any suggestion on how to resolve loop issue will be good as well, but crash is a blocker right now, so maybe disable this function will be a good temporary solution.

Comment: Curious question. Just a thought, didn’t `textField.autocorrectionType = .no` work?

Comment: Didn’t find any changes due to [this API differences site](http://codeworkshop.net/objc-diff/sdkdiffs/ios/13.0/)

Comment: have you find solution related to disable the quickpath ?